# Running Selenium via NUnit and Cruise Control .NET

Tags: nunit, selenium-webdriver, cruisecontrol.net

I'm having an issue running Selenium tests in NUnit from Cruise Control .NET.  I have a  simple test that runs fine when I run from the NUnit GUI on our continuous integration server.  However when the NUnit test is run from Cruise Control .NET on the same server, the test always fails.  Tests that don't use Selenium run fine from both the NUnit GUI and from Cruise Control.

```
[SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }



    [TearDown]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        Driver.Quit();
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Test basic Selenium functionality.
    /// </summary>
    [Test]
    public void SeleniumTest()
    {
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(TestConfig.TestURL);
        IWebElement testEle = WaitForElement(Driver, By.Id, "body", TestConfig.TestWaitMS);
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }



    private static IWebElement WaitForElement(IWebDriver driver, ByFunc byFunc, string elementId, int waitMs,
        string waitOutput = null, int pause = 50)
    {
        bool elementFound = false;
        int i = 0;
        IWebElement webElement = null;
        while (!elementFound && (i * pause) < waitMs)
        {
        try
        {
            webElement = driver.FindElement(byFunc(elementId));
            elementFound = true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            i++;
            Thread.Sleep(pause);
            if (waitOutput != null)
            Console.Write(waitOutput);
        }
        }
        if (elementFound)
        return webElement;
        else
        throw new NoSuchElementException(string.Format("Could not find element {0} after waiting {1}ms.", elementId, waitMs));
    }
```

WaitForElement is just a helper function that allows me to assign specific waits for certain elements rather than have a blanket waiting time for the entire test run.

The test fails when the NoSuchElementException is raised from the WaitForElement function.

I've found some links on Google saying that you need to run SeleniumRC as a service to get it to run from Cruise Control.  I don't think that applies here as I'm using the WebDriver version.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

1. IE version 8
2. Cruise Control .NET 1.8.3.0
3. NUnit 2.6
4. Selenium 2.0.0

Comment: Does it happen with other drivers? What version of Selenium specifically? (Current is v2.33) What version of the IEDriver? Your `WaitForElement` code is merely duplicate code of what is already there inside the library, specifically `WebDriverWait`. Have you actually tried running it under a service account? Did it make a difference?

Comment: @Arran Thanks for the suggestions.  I'll give them a go today.

Comment: @Arran Switching to Firefox fixed the issue so I guess the problem lies somewhere with the internet explorer driver.

Comment: That's great, although that's a workaround - is there any special need to have the IEDriver? (I pointed out trying other drivers merely to see if the problem existed in IE/IEDriver or your code) Did you set up your protected mode settings? https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: @Arran  Definitely a workaround.  I can't find the protected mode settings in the Windows Server 2003 version of IE8.  I'll update if I get time to come back to this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointers @Arran.  Switching to a Firefox driver fixed the issue.  I guess the fault must lie somewhere in the Internet Explorer driver.

```
[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
{
    Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```